# Oracle to PGSql

Tags: oracle, plpgsql, migrating

we are modernizing our application from oracle to postgres and moving to Azure cloud. We used Ora2pg tool to migrate schema and data. Now, I am facing issues with code.

```
i   integer       :=0;
tmp_cnt               integer;
tmp_Tab_Str           DBMS_UTILITY.UNCL_ARRAY;
tmp_Str_List_Quote    varchar(3000);

tmp_cnt_val               integer;
tmp_Tab_Str_val           DBMS_UTILITY.UNCL_ARRAY;
tmp_Str_List_Quote_val    varchar(3000);

tmp_attribute_id      bigint;
tmp_sysdate           timestamp;

BEGIN

    out_error_code := 0;
```

this is the part of the code and I am getting the below error while compiling.

```
ERROR:  schema "dbms_utility" does not exist
LINE 7: tmp_Tab_Str           DBMS_UTILITY.UNCL_ARRAY;
                              ^
SQL state: 3F000
Character: 520
```

Can somebody please help me with the solution.

```
ERROR:  schema "dbms_utility" does not exist
LINE 7: tmp_Tab_Str           DBMS_UTILITY.UNCL_ARRAY;
                              ^
SQL state: 3F000
Character: 520
```

Did not try any thing.

Comment: Ora2pg  utility does not completely convert oracle plsql code to pgsql,
you need to adapt the code for postgres.  type uncl_array IS table of VARCHAR2(32767) index by BINARY_INTEGER;

Comment: So, Can i declare it is TEXT[] in postgres?.

Comment: Yes, you can to declare  TEXT[] in postgres

Comment: character varying[]?. if i decare that as character varying[]?.